# how to get the number type of a contact in android?

Tags: android, contacts

I'm developing an application that uses the contacts ! to do some work ! and one of the most important things is the number type !

so if one contact have more than one number ! I need to get the number and the types ! 
I don't wan't to make the switch statement like this one

```
                int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                switch (type) {
                    case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        // do something with the Home number here...
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        // do something with the Mobile number here...
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        // do something with the Work number here...
                        break;
                 }
```

I need to get the type TEXT dynamiclly because most likely the my app works on the custom type ! 
not only Mobile and Work ... etc.

any help ?

EDIT :

I'm trying to get the contacts as this query :

> Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "
>   = " + id, null, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookupColumns.html#LABEL)

```
String typeLabel = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.LABEL));
```

Comment: it returns null all the time.

Comment: @daigoor Have you verified that what you're trying to return _isn't_ null?

Comment: I will accept the answer after I discovered that there are noway to get "Home" , "Work" , "Mobile" ..... LABEL only gets the custom String that provided by the client.

Comment: @Alex  Yes I did ! the type always returned 3 as an integer ! but I was trying to get type as "Home" instead to to write it manually in the code ! (String.xml)

Comment: @daigoor Without checking myself, it sounds like you just need to parse the enum to get the string value. Try _Phone.TYPE_HOME.name()_, etc.

Comment: Label only stores the custom type of String, in case user has decided to mark a number different from the types available. In other cases, the type is available as int and you might need to convert them into string types.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Rawkode's answer after the OP clarified he's looking for the phone type's label.

I found this online - seems Android has a built in way to get the labels *(disclosure: I haven't tested this yet)*

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
String home_label = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), Phone.TYPE_HOME, "");
```